# SQL function to return "most common value" for multiple columns in a Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to find the simplest way to return the most common value in multiple column results of a select statement that is grouped.  Everything I am finding online points to RANK on a single item in the select or dealing with each column separately outside of a GROUP BY.

Sample Data:

```
SELECT 100 as "auser", 
'A' as "instance1", 'M' as "instance2" 
union all select 100, 'B', 'M' 
union all select 100,'C', 'N' 
union all select 100, 'B', 'O'
union all select 200,'D', 'P' 
union all select 200, 'E', 'P' 
union all select 200,'F', 'P' 
union all select 200, 'F', 'Q'
```

Sample Data result:

```
auser   instance1   instance2
100     A           M
100     B           M
100     C           N
100     B           O
200     D           P
200     E           P
200     F           P
200     F           Q
```

Query logic (how I see it in my head):

```
SELECT auser, most_common(instance1), most_common(instance2)
FROM datasample
GROUP BY auser;
```

Desired result:

```
100     B           M
200     F           P
```

Comment: Please specify the rdbms your using

Comment: What if there is a tie?

Comment: SQL Server.  If there is a tie, I would like to wrap it in a MIN(), but I would like to see if this is even possible first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach to solving this problem uses nested window functions.  The innermost subquery calculates the count for each column.  The next subquery ranks these (using `row_number()` ).  The outer query then uses conditional aggregation to get the results that you want:

```
select auser, MAX(case when seqnum1 = 1 then instance1 end),
       MAX(case when seqnum2 = 1 then instance2 end)
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by auser order by cnt1 desc) as seqnum1,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by auser order by cnt2 desc) as seqnum2
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by auser, instance1) as cnt1,
                   COUNT(*) over (partition by auser, instance2) as cnt2
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by auser
```

Comment: Any ideas how to do this on Sqlite? I'm getting a `SQL logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error`

Comment: @Tyson . . . SQLite does not support the same set of functionality as SQL Server.  You can pose another question, tagged SQLite, to address your issue.

Comment: Great. It helped me. The only suggestion is to use two WITH queries instead of two subnested subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I can find something much more elegant, but this may do if you're on SQL 2005+ (since I'm using a [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) and [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)):

```
with instance1 as (
    select auser, instance1
        , row_number() over (partition by auser order by count(*) desc, instance1) as row_num
    from datasample
    group by auser, instance1
), instance2 as (
    select auser, instance2
        , row_number() over (partition by auser order by count(*) desc, instance2) as row_num
    from datasample
    group by auser, instance2
)
select a.auser, a.instance1, b.instance2
from instance1 as a 
    join instance2 as b on a.auser = b.auser
where a.row_num = 1
    and b.row_num = 1
order by a.auser;
```

I'm not sure how you wish to handle nulls, and moving the row_num equivalency to the join condition doesn't change the execution plan on my box.

If you're on SQL Server 2000, then you can replace these CTEs with derived tables and fake the row_number() through the use of count and a ["triangular join"](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/).

Comment: Yes, was hoping for something more elegant, as you state.  I simplified what I am actually working with.  "auser" is actually a series of about 10 columns that are considered in the group by, so that is adding to the difficulty (everywhere auser is here would be a listing of about 10 items).  Also, my data sample here is in reality the result of a 50 line query.  This is why I was hoping for a simple nested function type solution, but I don't think that will happen here.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO thank you for being the only one to reject that unnecessary code format edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go Through Simple

```
Select auser, instance1, instance2 FROM datasample GROUP BY auser,instance1, instance2 ;
```

Comment: How does that answer the question to find the most common values??