# Sort my List of records by the most frequent values then the next most frequent

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Sort my List of records so the records with the most in common values are displayed first.

[I thought I found the solution in this link, but this only sorts by the first value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651988/get-most-frequently-used-values-with-linq)

My unsorted list look like this...

[image]

I would like my sorted list to look like this....

[image]

The Code I tired based on the above link...

```
   lp = lp.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
              .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
              .SelectMany(g => g).ToList();


    dataGridView2.DataSource = lp;
```

But as explained this only sorts by the first most common item.

Comment: You grouped on name, which appears to be unique, was that a typo in the question or did you make the same mistake in your code? I would expect you would like to group by Value1, possibly by `new { x.Value1, x.Value2, x.Value3 }`?

Comment: No that was deliberate, as it later sorts by the record with the most in common. It just doesn't then sort by the next most common fields and the next and so on.

Comment: Is the Name column unique? It is not clear by which column/columns do you want to sort. Can you explain?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you mea nby "sort by the next most common field"? Do you mean you want to pick whether to sort by Value1, Value2, Value3 or Value4, or do you want to sort by Value1 and have the value that occurs the most times in that column sorted first?

Comment: I want to sort by the records (people) that have the most in common, i.e. Bob Steve and bill have the most values in common. so they should be first in the list then Jim and Simon have the most in common so they should be next etc.

Comment: Are you querying from the database? Or from an in-memory collection?

Comment: in-memory it is just a list of a custom type

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088964/sql-function-to-return-most-common-value-for-multiple-columns-in-a-group-by. It may help you a lot :)

Comment: try this :  Var result = lp.OrderBy(c => c.Value1).ThenBy(n => n.Value2).ThenBy(n => n.Value3)

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia please post your comment as an answer - i believe that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var result = lp.OrderBy(c => c.Value1).ThenBy(n => n.Value2).ThenBy(n => n.Value3)
```

Comment: This orders by each one in turn I need to order by the 'rows that have the most values the same.  I am going to spend this morning working out a convoluted solution to this and see if anyone can make it more slick with linq.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood well... You can try this

```
lp.Select(t => new {
    Thing = t, Coincidences = lp.Max(t2 =>
        t2 != t ?
        Convert.ToInt32(t2.Value1 == t.Value1) +
        Convert.ToInt32(t2.Value2 == t.Value2) +
        Convert.ToInt32(t2.Value3 == t.Value3) +
        Convert.ToInt32(t2.Value4 == t.Value4)
        : 0)
}).OrderByDescending(d => d.Coincidences).Select(d => d.Thing);
```